# How to decode filename.g726 coded information?

Tags: audio, adpcm

I have tried all ways to play the g726 codec file but not able to found decoder or how to play the g726 file.

I have tried with ffmpeg,mplayer,aplay.

Comment: You tried what, using what, how and where? Please, be more specific, unfortunately not everybody is a clairvoyant here yet.

Comment: Any update @musicamante ?

Comment: Support for g726 files already exists in ffmpeg since 6-7 years at least, if you don't have a really old version, you should be able to decode it. If it doesn't work, the file you're using is probably damaged or malformed. Could you share that file somewhere?

Comment: @musicamante can u please ping me at sdeep038@gmail.com